I'm writing code in react, and trying to display a pdf file inside a web page. but instead of the expected file, I see the same web page in that place
I'm writing code in react, and trying to display a pdf file inside a web page.
but instead of the expected file, I see the same web page in that place.
It means that there is a place destinated to that file (there is a scroll bar), but instead of viewing the pdf file- I see the web page were I am. the same buttons, inputs and so on.
someone can help me please?
here is my code:
for now it's only a try to check if the pdf is shown correctly. later I'll get the document by a request to a data service.
I have 3 components:

Document
this component shows a button to display or hide the pdf file.

export const Document = () => {

    const [documentDisplay, setDocumentDisplay] = useState(false);

    return <>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setDocumentDisplay(!documentDisplay)
                }}>document details</button>

        {
            documentDisplay && <DocumentDisplay documentId={0}/>
        }
    </>
}


DocumentDisplay
this component will request a document from a data service

export const DocumentDisplay = ({ documentId }) => {

    function requestDocument(documentId){

     // this function will return the file
     // for now, it just return the relative path to my file
        if(documentId == 0)
            return "/src/document/file.pdf"
    }
    
    return <>
        <Model document={requestDocument(documentId)}></Model>
    </>
}


Model
this component have to show my pdf on the web page, but instead of- shows the web page as explain above.

export const Model = ({document}) => {
    return <>
        <object
            name='pdf_show'
            type='application/pdf'
            data={document}
            width="60%"
            height="500px">
        </object>
    </>
}

the document received is the relative path to my pdf file.
I tried also to use the <iframe> and <embed> tags, but them both given me the same result.

If you access that PDF by it's path, do you get a website or the PDF? I mean like pasting the URL to the address bar.

@JakubKotrs
it's the relative path. so I don't get the pdf file. but neither the web page.
I've tried to send the full local path of my pdf- but then I got another bug- that I can't get access to a local file

That kind of answers it. It's relative but inaccessible, so when the browser makes that request, the server returns the homepage or something, no?

@JakubKotrs I thought that this is my problem. but - do you know how should I able to chrome access to my file? because I didn't find any solution for now

You can't. Imagine if websites could access your files, that'd be a big security issue.

@JakubKotrs
ok, so, if I understood well, the only issue is to upload my files to a domain on the internet, right?
